# How to generate screenshot for all test cases individually in Playwright C#?

Tags: c#, screenshot, playwright

When (Playwright C# - Data Driven Framework) test suit is ran then only one screeshot was generated and that was of last test cases in suit.

I tied below at the end of each test case required screenshot taken,where AccessCodeSearchResultPage is path defined in string.

await page.ScreenshotAsync(new() { Path = AccessCodeSearchResultPage, FullPage = true});

I expect it to generate screenshot with timestamp for every test case individually in which its included.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.